# Why won't the NPC move in?

Tags: terraria-mobile

One of my NPC's constantly wants to move in and I have 3 rooms available but it won't settle down. The NPC's name is Reishi by the way.

Answer (score -3):

Your houses have to be  certain lengths and heights.
Try making your houses 11 tiles long and 6 tiles high it'll work.